# How to solve this sequence $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n+1)^2}}$$

Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n .$
My attempt is [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAQmp.png)

Comment: What’s your attempt, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Answer (score 1):

We will use the squeeze theorem to evaluate this limit.

First, one can show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq 2$. To do this, note that:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n+1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\cdots + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = \frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}$, where the equality follows because there are $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$ terms. Now, using a standard formula, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}} = 2$, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq 2$.

Now, we need to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \geq 2$. We can use a similar trick as above here.

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+2}}+\cdots + \frac{1}{n+1} > \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{2n+1}{n+1}$, where again equality follows because we have $2n+1$ terms. Again, it is clear that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2n+1}{n+1} = 2$, so we have that $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \geq 2$.

Now, as $2 \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq 2$, we must have $\boxed{\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 2}$.

Please let me know if you have any more questions or suggestions! Apologies if my argument is not rigorous enough, I am fresh out of calc 2 with not much experience writing proofs like this.

Sidenote: I tried to look for a closed form for the summation, pretty sure one doesn't exist, wolfram alpha returns a result in terms of some weird function so if someone can find something let me know.

Comment: Nice solution...

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel has given a great solution. Here is another.

We  have a total of $2n + 1$ terms.

Adding the first two terms, we get $\frac{\sqrt{n^2 + 1} + \sqrt{n^2 + 2}}{\sqrt{n^4+ 3n^2 + 2}}$ which for large $n$ simplifies to $\frac{2}{n}$.

Adding the first $2n$ terms gives us $n \frac{2}{n} = 2$. We can skip the last term.

Answer (score 0):

From the graph of the function $y=\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}$ where $n$ is fixed, we have
$$\int_2^{2n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}dx<x_n<\int_1^{2n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}dx.$$
Now,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_2^{2n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}2(n+1-\sqrt{n^2+2})=2$$
and similarly $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_1^{2n+1}\frac1{\sqrt{n^2+x}}dx=2.$ So, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=2$ by the squeeze theorem.